# distance_of_time_in_words but just (HR:MIN:SEC)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I'm looking for something similar to distance_of_time_in_words() but rather than the 'in_words' part I would like something in the format similar to this:

'hours:mins:seconds'

or even:

'days:hours:mins:seconds'

Is there an easy custom way to do this?

EDIT: found a related post, answered:
[Rails: distance_of_time_NOT_in_words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430249/rails-distance-of-time-not-in-words)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails: distance_of_time_NOT_in_words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430249/rails-distance-of-time-not-in-words)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this here: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Dates_and_Times_in_Ruby

Seems to be what you're looking for.

```
require 'date'

today = DateTime.now
=> #<DateTime: 441799066630193/180000000,-301/1440,2299161>

birthday = Date.new(2008, 4, 10)
=> #<Date: 4909133/2,0,2299161>

days_to_go = birthday - today

time_until = birthday - today
=> Rational(22903369807, 180000000)

time_until.to_i             # get the number of days until my birthday
=> 127

hours,minutes,seconds,frac = Date.day_fraction_to_time(time_until)
[3053, 46, 57, Rational(1057, 180000000)]

puts "It is my birthday in #{hours} hours, #{minutes} minutes and #{seconds} seconds (not that I am counting)"
It is my birthday in 3053 hours, 46 minutes and 57 seconds (not that I am counting)
```